# Perl Soap::Schema Output

Tags: perl, web-services, soap, wsdl, schema

To call a web service I always use SOAP::Schema and use returned parameters as follow:

```
my $wsdl     = "wsdl adres";

my $schema   = SOAP::Schema->new( schema_url => $wsdl )->parse();
my $services = $schema->services();

my $first_key = undef;
foreach my $key (keys %$services) {
 $first_key = $key unless ($first_key);
}

my $proxy      = "$$services{$first_key}{$method}{endpoint}";
my $uri        = "$$services{$first_key}{$method}{soapaction}";
my $ns         = "$$services{$first_key}{$method}{namespace}";
my $parameters = $$services{$first_key}{$method}{parameters};

my $soap = SOAP::Lite
    -> on_action( sub { join '/', @_ } )
    -> readable(1)
    -> uri($uri)
    -> proxy($proxy)
    -> ns("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/","soapenv")
    -> ns($ns);
```

It always worked, but now I got following error for a new wsdl adress:

*mismatched tag at line 8, column 2, byte 84 at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/i386-linux-thread-multi/XML/Parser.pm line 187*

What may problem be? wsdl definition is correct because it works when I try from SOAPUI.

Comment: means your xml is broken. You should dump it and inspect to see what you get. (probably not XML, might be an error page)

Comment: But it works when I call web service via SOAP UI. I think this shows that xml is not broken, am I wrong?

Comment: That's literally an error generated from your parser saying your XML is broken. Likely cause is it isn't actually XML, but HTML that starts out valid but because the spec is looser, it can't be parsed.

Comment: This is the xml I am using to parse. How can I find uri, proxy from an XML definition. Until today I always did it as bu using SOAP::Schema but it does not work now.       http://xperiaclub.com/Service/Service1.svc?singleWsdl

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, this is only a partial answer - because the URL you gave *does* work, but that error you have is specifically a problem with the XML you've fetched *not* parsing.

So going back to basics:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict; 
use warnings 'all';
use LWP::Simple;
use XML::Twig; 

my $url = 'http://xperiaclub.com/Service/Service1.svc?singleWsdl';

my $content = get ( $url );
my $twig = XML::Twig -> parse ( $content );
$twig -> set_pretty_print ( 'indented_a');
$twig -> print;
```

This will error if the content is invalid XML - and it isn't, it works fine. Which doesn't answer your question, I know.

So this XML isn't the problem.

Comment: why do you say that the URL does not work? Did you get error when clicked on URL? It works:   http://xperiaclub.com/Service/Service1.svc?singleWsdl

Comment: I didn't. I said it _does_ work. It works fine. This is not your error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at my server. My server is redirecting URL to a wrong one, xml is not found and this error occurs